Help installing a bidet shower
I would like to install a bidet shower in my bathroom. I am used to DIY tasks, but I've never done any plumbing jobs. I am seeking help with how/where to install the 't' connectors required to connect the bidet to my existing pipes.
I have looked at the pipes, and I've found the following:

As you can see from the picture below, there is an existing connection between the cold water pipe and the WC tank.

I am sorry for being ignorant about this; I have also noticed some valves (?) on both the cold and hot water pipes going toward the bathtub (shown at the bottom of the picture below), and I was wondering what they are used for.

Based on the existing pipe arrangement above, can anybody suggest the best way to connect the bidet shower? I was thinking of purchasing one with a thermostatic valve that would, therefore, require both hot and cold water input and would produce as output a mixed water flow at the right temperature going into the shower bidet.

Never heard of a bidet shower before.  Where are you located?

The valves with the red and blue handles are used to isolate the bath-end of the pipes. That way you can do work, such as replacing the taps, without having to cut off the water to the whole house. I suggest that you always fit isolating valves to new items. Also, put labels on what pipes go to and use permanent ink. (I am not a qualified plumber.)

@Huesmann I am Italian, leaving in the UK. We usually have a dedicated bidet in our bathrooms in Italy but now somebody is installing handheld bidet showers in case they lack space for a separate bidet. I can see these handheld showers are sold in the UK too.

@AndrewMorton Thanks. I knew about those and I was referring, in fact, to the other valves, at the bottom of the third pictures.

@ilSaturo Oh, you mean the drain cocks?

Honestly, if you're having this much angst figuring out which piping to connect to, the easy button may be to simply get a bidet toilet seat, which installs using the same plumbing supply valve as the toilet.

@AndrewMorton Thanks, now I understand what they are and I assume they can't be used to attach any pipes :) as they are used as drain point?

@Huesmann, that was my initial idea - a Japanese toilet seat. However, I have struggled to find one that fits my square-shaped toilet. Also, I have a recessed water tank, and locating the valve you mentioned is difficult.

If the type of bidet shower you have in mind is simply a handheld miniature shower head, intended to be used while sitting on the toilet: there are models which simply screw onto a vanity faucet instead of the aerator (example). The faucet will work as usual unless you press the button on the bidet shower, in which case water comes out of the shower head.
These are a 5-minute job to install (not even) and won’t introduce any risk of leaks as long as the faucet is turned off (and if you turn it on, you would likely notice leaks very soon).
They’re available in most of Europe – not sure where you are based and what the situation is there, but I would look into it.
As an alternative, there are even vanity faucets with an extra hose for a bidet shower (example). They’re only slightly more expensive than a regular faucet, and you’d need to replace the entire faucet, but maybe that is an option too.

Thanks. My vanity faucet is recessed behind a mirror and not easily accessible, so maybe this is not an option. Regarding option 2, if I got it properly, it would actually need a hose attached to the regular faucet, which I am not happy with from an ecstatic viewpoint.

With option 2, the faucet comes with a hose that connects to the bottom and comes out under the vanity. With option 1, you would indeed have a hose running across your vanity – granted, not the most elegant option but a quick retrofit.

I’ve added links to examples for the products, hope that makes it clearer.

Insert the taps in the hot and cold lines going to the shower.  Given your level of experience, I would suggest you use only prefabricated flexible lines made with connectors that match the existing ones. Most problems arise from leaks due to imperfect connections.
As usual, follow the instructions, especially with regard to tightening (neither too much nor too little).  You may benefit from YouTube or other online guidance.

Are you suggesting using the valves at the bottom of the third picture? Is it possible to use them? What are they usually used for?

No, not those (which I think are drain cocks used to empty the line, frequently for outdoor hose faucets that need to be drained each winter to prevent freeze damage).   I am referring to the red and blue valves in the lines at the top, which I assume are used to isolate (shut off) the hot and cold lines to the valves in the shower.  (You can confirm this by turning them off and seeing if the shower still works.).  After you shut off the water supply, disconnect the shower from the valve, insert the tap ("tee" in US), and reconnect.  Take pix to plumbing store to get the right fittings.
